# Cordova Ajax communication with server does not work

Tags: php, android, ajax, cordova

I am a phonegap beginner.

I just develop the simple sign up page.  Also I make the simple php code in my local.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "wifoot";
// Create connection
$con_main = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$con_main) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user(email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$password')";
$result = $con_main->query($sql);
if ($con_main->connect_error)
{
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'fail');
}
else{

    $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => 'success');
}
$con_main->close();

category($json);
function category($answer){
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($answer);
}
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
 $("#create-account").click(function(){

    var email =   $("#create_email").val();
    var pass  =   $("#create_password").val();

    if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:81/index.php",
            type: 'POST',    
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {email: email, pass: pass},
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data.msg);
                if(data.status == '1'){
                     window.location = "welcome.html";
                }
                else{
                    alert("Having some connection issue...");
                     window.location = "welcome.html";
                }
            },
            complete: function () {

            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Having some connection issue...");
                window.location = "welcome.html";
            }
        });
    }
```

});

It works well on my local. But when I build the android, it always says 'connect error'.

OK.   I fixed it by myself. That is very simpe.
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://sample.com">`

As you can I just add this meta.   In the 'connect-src',  I add the url.  So it works well.  I think it will help for phone gap beginner.
Thanks

Comment: It works well. Thanks Naresh Kumar.

Answer (score -1):

You can't connect to local server through mobile app by using **localhost**. Instead of **localhost** use your **ipaddress** in ajax call.

And make sure the server and the phone are on the same network.

Comment: Hi, sir. thanks for your response.  So I replace with 'http://192.168.1.107:81/index.php'.    But it has still same error.

Comment: Have u changed in config.xml also ?

Comment: Also try changing the parameter in ajax call as follows.                        

data: JSON.stringify({email: email, pass: pass})